# Does RxPy have a `flatten` operator?

Tags: python, reactive-programming, rx-py

Does RxPy have a convenient `flatten` operator which is equivalent to `flat_map(identity)`? Or have `flat_map`'s `selector` default to `identity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Dag Brattli](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/issues/98)

> You can use .merge_all().

Comment: Is this any different from `.flat_map(lambda x: x)`? Or is it just shorter to type?